# The "android" command is deprecated

Tags: android, sdk

I recently saw this info from Android:

```
C:\...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools>android list sdk
**************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************

"android" SDK commands can be translated to sdkmanager commands on a best-effort
basis.
(This prompt can be suppressed with the --use-sdk-wrapper commend-line argument
or by setting the USE_SDK_WRAPPER environment variable)
Continue? [y/N]:
```

Does that mean the 'android' command shouldn't be used at all now?

Comment: Quick question: why did you set the react-native tag?

Comment: I came to this problem while trying to set up environment for react-native app with Android SDK as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html]).